# How to create array display on function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, domdocument

I have given four images the same class name and placed them inside a div. Currently the image before is set to display with the four set to not show in CSS. I am attempting to have the images display onmouseover through Javascript. I can do it through CSS but would like to see it through Javascript. Below is the code:

HTML

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');
var Larrow = document.getElementById('arrow1');
var Rarrow = document.getElementById('arrow2');
var slidpics = document.getElementByClassName('crash');
var stop = document.getElementsByClassName('picbac');
var display = 0;

first.onmouseover = function() {
  if (x = 0, x < slidpics.length, x++) {
    slidpics[display].style.display = 'inline-flex';
    display++;
  }
}

stop.onmouseout = function() {
  var y;
  if (y = 0, y < slidpics.length, y++) {
    slidpics[display].style.display = 'none';
    display++;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = "picbac"></div>
<img id="first" src="../Pics  /January_2019/crash1.jpg" alt="A picture you can't see">
<p id="arrow1"></p>
<img id="show1" class="crash" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash2.jpg" alt="Another picture you can't see">
<img id="show2" class="crash" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash3.jpg" alt="You must be blind">
<img id="show3" class="crash" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash4.jpg" alt="Or we're not linking up">
<p id="arrow2"></p>
<img id="show4" class="crash" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash5.jpg" alt="Still checkin?">
```

Comment: Not going to give an answer, but it seems that you want to do loops, and loops are made with `for` and `;` (you used `if` and `,`).

Answer (score 1):

A good way is keep off the style from the script and to just assign a class to the `.picbac` container so as to show the `.crash` children with display: inline-flex

```
var first = document.getElementById('first');
var picbac = document.querySelector('.picbac');

first.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  picbac.classList.add('show');
});
picbac.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  picbac.classList.remove('show');
});
```

on mouseenter/mouseleave a `.show` class is toggled on the `.picbac` element, so the CSS could be

```
.picbac .crash {
  display: none;
}

.picbac.show .crash {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

This approach is possible as long as your `.crash` images are children of the `.picbac` element and this simplifies a lot the code and it decouples the logic (behaviour and appearance).

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvWqZY)

Comment: #first is its own but under .picbac because I want tall the pics inline, same line. I might be able to hold a lil somethin from this

Comment: I added  classList function and did add and remove list but it still doesn't work when all pics are inline for some reason. Any idea how to make that work?

Comment: @Sdrah in my answer there is a demo. Try it

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this but this is one if you dont mind jquery.

```js
// show the first image in the set as default
$("#wrapper > .content:first-of-type").children("img").show();

// show images on mouse enter
$(".content p").on("mouseenter", function(){
  $(this).closest(".content").children("img").show();
});

// hide the images on mouse out
$(".content p").on("mouseout", function(){
  $(this).closest(".content").children("img").hide();
});
```

```css
.content img{
  display: none;
}

.content p:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
  <p>--></p>

    <img id="first" src="../Pics  /January_2019/crash1.jpg" alt="A picture you can't see">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  <p class="arrow">--></p>
    <img id="show1" class="crash" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash2.jpg" alt="Another picture you can't see">
    <img id="show2" class="crash" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash3.jpg" alt="You must be blind">
    <img id="show3" class="crash" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash4.jpg" alt="Or we're not linking up">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
  <p class="arrow">--></p>

    <img id="show4" class="crash" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash5.jpg" alt="Still checkin?">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I havent fuked with JQ yet... heard its easier than straight up JS but I'm lookin too nail what I know first

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need an array to achieve what you're describing.

Using JQuery with minimal code, I use the arrows to trigger `fadeIn()` of the images.

```js
var imgsDiv = $("#picbac").children();

imgsDiv.on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this.children[1]).fadeIn(500); //you can use show()
});

imgsDiv.on("mouseout", function() {
  $(this.children[1]).fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
.crash {
  display: none;
}

[id^=container]{
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 20px;
  width : 80vw;
}

p{
font-weight: 900;
}

img{
width: 50%; 
height: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picbac">
  <div id="container1">
    <p id="arrow1">Show 1</p>
    <img id="show1" class="crash" src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg" alt="Another picture you can't see">
  </div>
  
  <div id="container2">
    <p id="arrow2">Show 2</p>
    <img id="show2" class="crash" src="https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg" alt="You must be blind">
  </div>
  
  <div id="container3">
    <p id="arrow3">Show 3</p>
    <img id="show3" class="crash" src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg" alt="Or we're not linking up">
  </div>
  
  <div id="container4">
    <p id="arrow4">Show 4</p>
    <img id="show4" class="crash" src="https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg" alt="Still checkin?">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.